# How can I update a two-column Access table with the last entry of each column 2 whenever there's a repeating entry of column 1?

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

To illustrate my example a little better, this is generally the kind of thing I'm looking for:

This is what I'm starting with:

```
Column 1 | Column 2
-------------------
    A    |   1
    B    |   2
    A    |   3
```

I'd like to end with either:

1) this is preferable because there will be less data in the table, but definitely not necessary

```
Column 1 | Column 2
-------------------
    A    |   3
    B    |   2
```

2)

```
Column 1 | Column 2
-------------------
    A    |   3
    B    |   2
    A    |   3
```

So to explain a little more clearly, I have a table with a bunch of data in it. The user can import data whenever they went. The issue is that occasionally some entries will be updated. In that case, I need all the entries in the table to be updated with whatever the last data added states. For example, if originally A has a value of 1, and the table is later updated with an entry that says A has a value of 3, I need to update the entire table to show that A only has a value of 3.

Also, while I know how to do this on a query, I need to be able to do it on a table. Right now I've thought of a couple of ideas, but none of them seem to work. I've tried an update query along the lines of:

```
"UPDATE tblData SET column2 = Last(Column2) GROUP BY Column1"
```

but this doesn't really seem to work. I've also tried:

```
"UPDATE tblData Set Column2 = DLast('Column2', 'tblData')"
```

which is much closer. However it's updating all the entries with the last record to look like this:

```
Column 1 | Column 2
-------------------
    A    |   3
    B    |   3
    A    |   3
```

I'm guessing this is because there is no "GROUP BY" clause to tell it to only do it for each instance of Column1, but through research it doesn't look like you can put a "GROUP BY" in an "UPDATE" statement. How should I approach this to get the result I'm looking for?

EDIT: Also, while I'm not 100% sure about this, I think the way to solve this is to use the third optional parameter of DLast, the [criteria] parameter. The only way I can think of using this is to specify an exact value for Column1 which is why I'm not sure how to use it here, but I feel like there has to be a way to manipulate it to apply to each individual value of Column1.

Comment: `DLast()` depends on the ordering of the rows; without explicitly defining the ordering, `DLast()` is not reliable. `tblData` is an unordered bag of data. The db engine does not know which was the "last" row added. It's not like an Excel spreadsheet. You need to tell the db engine how to determine the sequence of rows ... a `date_added` field could do it.

Comment: Hey, I'm not sure where your comment went but I was just about to mark it correctly. Your answer worked sort of. Instead of DMax() I used DLast() and the inner apostrophes had to be changed to chr(34). Are you sure DLast() doesn't know what the last row is? Since I don't order it, I was under the impression it defaults to using the bottom of table (ie. the data added most recently). I've tried several tests and it's working so far but I might be overlooking something. Could you give me an example of a situation where it wouldn't work?

Answer (score 0):

KryptKeeper - to HansUp's response, updates to column2 are not necessarily HIGHER numbers are they? If not, then the max(column2) won't work. You didn't mention if your table is a counter or an accumulator or something like that. If the updated records can go down in value as well in column 2, then you may have to carry a datetime stamp as an extra column so you can grab the max() on the datetime column instead.

Comment: Oh yeah sorry, I was planning to mention it at the bottom of my comment to HansUp but I forgot. You're right, it can definitely go both ways, but I don't mind if someone explains it in terms of dmax because it's essentially the same logic. I would just switch out dmax to dlast in the final code.